# Proving a formula with binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Is this formula true? How can I prove it?
$$\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}2s =2^{n-1}(n-1)$$

Thanks!

Comment: you can use induction or simply expand and observe what happens for first two and last two terms determine a pattern and make a conclusion and this formula indeed is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\binom {n-1}{s}\frac{s}{n-1} = \binom{n-2}{s-1} $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Consider $$f(x) = (1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix}n-1\\s\end{pmatrix}x^s. $$ Your sum is related to $f'(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use $n-1$ as the upper limit.  Let me recast it with $m=n-1$.  I'll also divide both sides by $2$.  Then you have

$\sum_{s=0}^m s \binom{m}{s}$  on the left and $m2^{m-1}$ on the right.

Let's see what is being counted on the left.  Consider a set of $m$ objects.  Each term on the left is the total number of subsets of size s times the number of things in the size s  subsets.

You may be aware that there are $2^m$ total subsets of $m$ objects.  If I divide by $2^m$, then the left hand side is the expected number of elements in a random subset of $m$.  The right hand side is $m/2$.   Does the average subset have size $m/2$?  There's an elegant way to pair up subsets to show this.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}2s 
&=2\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}\binom s1\\
&=2\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{1}\binom {n-2}{s-1}\qquad \text{(subset of a subset)}\\
&=2\binom{n-1}1\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{s-1}\\
&=2(n-1)\sum_{s=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{s}\\
&=2(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}\\\\
&=2^{n-1}(n-1)\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$